# C: Unresolved external symbol (function name) found in function option. LINK 2019 error

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int hours; //hours worked.
double rate; //Hourly rate
double regular; //Regular pay
double overtime; //how many hours the user worked overtime.
double gross; //Gross salary
double federal; //Federal tax of 27%
double medical; //medical insurance, 14%
double net; // Pay after federal tax and medical insurance is taken out.
char c[1];
int Running = 1;
int f = -1;
void option(int opt);


main(void) {

    void workStats(void); //Function that will collect user's number of hours and how much they make an hour.
    void regularPay(void);
    void grossPayWithOvertime(void);
    void totalPayTakingOutTaxes(void);
    void printMenu(void);

    void printMenu(void);
    while (Running == 1) {
        scanf("%d", &f);
        option(f);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
void option(int option) {
    switch (option) {
    case 1:
        workStats();
        break;
    case 2:
        regularPay();
        break;
    case 3:
        grossPayWithOvertime();
        break;
    case 4:
        totalPayTakingOutTaxes();
        break;
    case 5:
        Running = 0;
        break;

    default:
        printf("Sorry, but that was not an option; Please enter one of our choices. Type any number between 1 and 6.");
        system("pause");
    }
        void printMenu(void); {
            printf("==========================================================\n");
            printf("===========Payroll Program==========================\n");
            printf("============================================================\n\n");
            printf("Things you can do here.\n");
            printf("\n1. Tell us about how much you make and how many hours you work \n");
            printf("\n2. Regular Pay, before taxes are included\n");
            printf("\n3. Gross PAy (This includes overtime) \n");
            printf("\n4. Net pay (Taxes taken out of Gross Pay) \n");
            printf("\n5. Exit");

            printf("Please type the number corresponding to the action you wish to take. \n");
        }
        void workStats(void); {
            printf("Now, how many hours do you work a week?");
            scanf("%d", &hours);

            printf("Please tell me how much you make per hour.");
            scanf("%lf", &rate);
        }
        void regularPay(void); {

            regular = rate * hours;

            printf("Regular Pay:%.2lf \n ", regular);
        }
        void grossPayWithOvertime(void); {
            overtime = (hours - 40) * (rate * 1.5);

            printf("Overtime Pay:%.2lf \n ", overtime);

            gross = regular + overtime;

            printf("Gross Pay:%.2lf \n ", gross);
        }
        void totalPayTakingOutTaxes(void); {
            federal = gross * .27;

            printf("Federal Tax:%.2lf  \n", federal);

            medical = gross * .14;

            printf("Medical Insurance :%.2lf \n ", medical);

            net = gross - (federal + medical);

            printf("Net Pay:%.2lf \n ", net);

            system("pause");

    }
}
```

The issue is  when I try to compile it does not recognize my function calls. A cleaning and rebuilding did not solve this issue, (I just programmed this today, so it was not sitting around or anything) and I don't have any outside files that I reference in this code so that is not the issue either. Any help is much appreciated.
Full Error:
https://puu.sh/wKn4n/00f95f3032.png

Comment: Are you 100 % sure that your compiler does not give you any warning? Which compiler?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017, and the warning it jjust gives me those errors, no warnings here.

Comment: I hope you do not write any software for the government bodies. If yes I am getting worried ...

Comment: It's usually of great help (also making the question complete) if the __full__ error (if any) is included.

Comment: I will suggest you take any good C book([C Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)) and take your time(no skipping chapters) to understand basic things. These are basic things and you have a very big problem with them.

Answer (score 4):

You have *two* problems: The first is that you declare the prototypes in the scope of the `main` function (which you forgot to give a return type by the way). The prototypes should be declared in the *global* scope.

The second problem is worse, since you're doing something completely invalid, and that is defining the function *inside* the`option` function. They should of course be defined (implemented) in the global scope as well. Defining nested function (functions inside other functions) is not valid C.

Comment: The problem is even more subtle - he's not actually *defining* a function within a function. He's declaring a function followed by semicolon and a block of code.  It just happens to compile....

Comment: So, write out what the functions do before main()?

Comment: Oh and the Semi colon are there because VS whined that there was not one there.

Answer (score 0):

The overall structure of your file should be like this:

```
#include <this.h>
#include <that.h>

int globalvar; // if you must have globals; you should try to avoid them

static void
workStats(void)
{
    // body of workStats here
}

static void
regularPay(void)
{
    // body of regularPay here
}
// and so on like that, for all functions besides main

int
main(void)
{
    // body of main here
    // you don't need to redeclare the functions
}
```