# C: The variables in my function are not recognized because my variables are not global

Tags: c

So, I defined my functions globally so they are recognized, but I'm not allowed to define my variables globally, and now my variables are not recognized within my function definitions. ( Error: "identifier -variableName- is undefined".) Any suggestions to solve this would be much appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#define PAUSE system("pause")
#define SIZE 10
int main(void) {
    void enterNumbers();
    void addNumbers();
    void numbersAveraged();
    void displayNumbers();
    int i = 0;
    int usersArray[SIZE] = { 0 };
    int numbers = 0;
    int totalOfInput = 0;
    int averageOfInput = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int option = 0;
    do {

        printf("==========================================================\n");
        printf("=================Number Management System====================\n");
        printf("============================================================\n\n");
        printf("Things you can do here.\n");
        printf("\n1. Give us numbers to work with! \n");
        printf("\n2. Let Me add all the numbers you gave me.\n");
        printf("\n3. I  will display the average of all of the numbers you've put in.\n");
        printf("\n4. I will display all of the numbers you put in. \n");
        printf("\n5. Exit \n");
        scanf("%i", &option);

        switch (option) {
        case 1:
            enterNumbers();
            break;
        case 2:
            addNumbers();

            break;
        case 3:
            numbersAveraged();
            break;
        case 4:
            displayNumbers();
            break;
        case 5:
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            printf("This is not a valid choice, please type 1-5. ");
            PAUSE;
        }


    } while (option != 5);

    void enterNumbers(); {
        for (i = 0; i == SIZE; i++) {
            printf("Please type in a number. Enter -1 when you are done entering numbers.");
            scanf("%i", &usersArray[i]);
            count++;
            if (usersArray[i] == -1) {
                break;
            }
            if (i == SIZE) {
                printf("That's enough numbers! I can't hold any more I'm afraid.");
            }
        }
    }
    void addNumbers(); {
        void enterNumbers();
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            totalOfInput += usersArray[i];
        }
        printf("OK, so the total of all of these numbers is: %d", totalOfInput);
    }
    void numbersAveraged(); {
        addNumbers();
        averageOfInput = totalOfInput / i;
        printf(" The average of the numbers you added was %i", averageOfInput);
    }
    void displayNumbers(); {
        printf("OK, here are all of the numbers you put in. \n");
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            printf("%d \n", usersArray[i]);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nested functions are not supported in standard C.

Comment: You still have the same problems as [in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121296/c-unresolved-external-symbol-function-name-found-in-function-option-link-201). Fix those first!

Comment: Learning the language would help. Don't skip chapters in your book and don't youtube during course lessons.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Look closely at the "nested functions". There are sneaky semicolons between the closing parenthesis and opening curly bracket. They are function prototypes followed by blocks of code.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Wow. So nested function prototypes :)

Comment: You're supposed to use function parameters and return values for communicating between functions.

Comment: Are you coding C programming language?

Comment: I am I'm trying to understand the language. I've been reading my book  and watching my lessons, neither really cover putting functions in this switch case structure which has beenm really messing me up.

Comment: try to read some standard easy tutorial on C complete for example tutorialspoint

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/

Answer (score 0):

C has not nested function.
We declare Global variable in C above `main()`.
To store Average of some numbers we must define a floating point variable that can hold Rational numbers (i.e. 5.69) because of a/b may have not integer answer(10/3=3.33). `float averageOfInput = 0;`

I perform some basic changes on your source and it works. but this is not a Good or complete version. you can improve it by learning more  C.

## Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#define PAUSE system("pause")
#define SIZE 5


///Global Variables
int usersArray[SIZE] = { 0 };
int count = 0;
int numbers = 0;
int totalOfInput = 0;
float averageOfInput = 0;   
int i = 0;

///Function declaration 
void enterNumbers();
void addNumbers();
void numbersAveraged();
void displayNumbers();


int main(void)
{

    
    int option = 0;
    
    do {
    
    printf("\n");
    
    
    printf("==========================================================\n");
    printf("=================Number Management System====================\n");
    printf("============================================================\n\n\n\n");
    printf("Things you can do here.\n");
    printf("\n1. Give us numbers to work with! \n");
    printf("\n2. Let Me add all the numbers you gave me.\n");
    printf("\n3. I  will display the average of all of the numbers you've put in.\n");
    printf("\n4. I will display all of the numbers you put in. \n");
    printf("\n5. Exit \n");
    
    scanf("%i", &option);

    switch (option) {
    case 1:
        enterNumbers();
        break;
    case 2:
        addNumbers();
        break;
    case 3:
        numbersAveraged();
        break;
    case 4:
        displayNumbers();
        break;
    case 5:
        exit(0);
        break;
    default:
        printf("This is not a valid choice, please type 1-5. ");
        PAUSE;
    }

    
    } while (option != 5);

}//End main()



///Function definition 

void enterNumbers() 
{
    int temp;
    printf("Please type in a number. Enter -1 when you are done entering numbers.\n");
        
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        scanf("%i", &temp);
        if (temp == -1) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            usersArray[i] = temp;   
            count++;
        }
        
    }
}


void addNumbers()
{
    totalOfInput = 0;
    enterNumbers();
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        totalOfInput += usersArray[i];
    }
    printf("OK, so the total of all of these numbers is: %d\n", totalOfInput);
}

void numbersAveraged(){
    addNumbers();
    averageOfInput = (float) totalOfInput / count;
    printf(" The average of the numbers you added was %f\n", averageOfInput);
}

void displayNumbers(){
    printf("OK, here are all of the numbers you put in.\n");
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%d \n", usersArray[i]);
    }
}
```